# Run specific function for exactly 2 hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

There is a function which is needed to run for 2 hours, Interrupting it manually after 2 hours is not desired in this case. What is the best practice to implement such a task?

```
def fib():
    sequence = [0,1]
    while True:
        sequence.append(sequence[-1]+sequence[-2])
    return sequence
```

I know it is possible to write such program using `time` library, but I'm curious if there is another way to do it in Python or not.

```
import time

def fib():
    sequence = [0,1]
    tic = time.time()
    while True:
        sequence.append(sequence[-1]+sequence[-2])
        toc = time.time()
        if toc-tic> 2*60*60: # reaching two hours
            break
    return sequence
```

Comment: Not really.  You don't ever want to terminate a running thread suddenly; it's always a better practice to have a loop or thread that knows how to stop itself.

Comment: @TimRoberts The original task is a simulation task. I need to simulate it for some hours and i don't want to interrupt it manually. The results of this simulation will be analyzed later. That's why i came up with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up the poll a bit by

```
import time

def fib():
    sequence = [0,1]
    end = time.time() + 2*60*60
    while time.time() < end:
        sequence.append(sequence[-1]+sequence[-2])
    return sequence
```

This adds the cost of `time.time()` on each loop, which can be significant - especially in this case. You could have some counter where you only call `time()` once every, say, 100 rounds of the loop.

Another option is to start a background thread the sleeps and then sets a varible to `True` when done. Wrap that in a class to make it look fancy and you'd have

```
import threading
import time

class TimeoutIndicator(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.done = False
        super().__init__(name="timeout_indicator", daemon=True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.timeout)
        self.done = True

    def __bool__(self):
        if self.done:
            self.join()
        return self.done

def fib(stop_now):
    sequence = [0,1]
    while not stop_now:
        sequence.append(sequence[-1]+sequence[-2])
    return sequence

fib(TimeoutIndicator(2*60*60))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. This is a clearer version of my code. Although `*` should be `+` when you're defining `end` variable. Do you have an alternate solution in mind for solving this problem?

Comment: Yes, but was pulled away. You could do signal.ALARM if you are on a unixy system and running the main thread. Or, a background thread that does nothing but sleep 2 hours and set a variable to True. This has the advantage that you don't incur the time.time() costs on each loop. I'll write that one up.